# Azure Storage Blob Download Progress Indicator

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

i need a progress indicator when downloading a blob.

The progress indicator already works when uploading. I'm using the Progresshandler within the **BlobUploadOptions**.

**BlobDownloadDetails** seems to have a progress status. However, I don't know how to integrate it to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
IKeyEncryptionKey key;
IKeyEncryptionKeyResolver keyResolver;

// Create the encryption options to be used for upload and download.
ClientSideEncryptionOptions encryptionOptions = new ClientSideEncryptionOptions(ClientSideEncryptionVersion.V2_0)
{
   KeyEncryptionKey = key,
   KeyResolver = keyResolver,
   // string the storage client will use when calling IKeyEncryptionKey.WrapKey()
   KeyWrapAlgorithm = "some algorithm name"
};

// Set the encryption options on the client options
BlobClientOptions options = new SpecializedBlobClientOptions() { ClientSideEncryption = encryptionOptions };

// Get your blob client with client-side encryption enabled.
// Client-side encryption options are passed from service to container clients, and container to blob clients.
// Attempting to construct a BlockBlobClient, PageBlobClient, or AppendBlobClient from a BlobContainerClient
// with client-side encryption options present will throw, as this functionality is only supported with BlobClient.
BlobClient blob = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString, options).GetBlobContainerClient("myContainer").GetBlobClient("myBlob");

        BlobUploadOptions uploadOptions = new BlobUploadOptions();
        uploadOptions.ProgressHandler = new Progress<long>(percent =>
        {
           progressbar.Maximum = 100;
           progressbar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(percent * 100 / file.Length);
        });

// Upload the encrypted contents to the blob.
blob.UploadAsync(content: stream, options: uploadOptions, cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);

// Download and decrypt the encrypted contents from the blob.
MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
blob.DownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `DownloadTo` method does not support progress monitor. When go through the source code, `DownloadTo` method is defined in `BlobBaseClient` class, but `UploadAsync` method is defined in `BlobClient` class which is inherited from `BlobBaseClient` class. So I think they may miss this feature in the base class `BlobBaseClient`.

But there is a workaround, the code as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("xxx");
        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("xxx");

        var blobToDownload = blobClient.Download().Value;
        
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

        var downloadBuffer = new byte[81920];
        int bytesRead;
        int totalBytesDownloaded = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = blobToDownload.Content.Read(downloadBuffer, 0, downloadBuffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(downloadBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalBytesDownloaded += bytesRead;
            Console.WriteLine(GetProgressPercentage(blobToDownload.ContentLength, totalBytesDownloaded));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("**completed**");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static double GetProgressPercentage(double totalSize, double currentSize)
    {
        return (currentSize / totalSize) * 100;
    }
}
```

Here is the [reference doc](https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/upload-or-download-file-from-azure-blob-storage-with-progress-percentage-csharp/).

Answer (score 0):

The DownloadStreamingAsync supports a progress callback so here is an alternate approach...

```
{
    ...
    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    var targetPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
    var prop = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
    var length = prop.Value.ContentLength;
    var download = await blobClient.DownloadStreamingAsync(new HttpRange(0, length),
        new BlobRequestConditions(),
        false,
        new ProgressTracker(log, length),
        CancellationToken.None);

    var data = download.Value.Content;

    await using (var fileStream = File.Create(targetPath))
    {
        await data.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}

private class ProgressTracker : IProgress<long>
{
    private readonly TextWriter _logWriter;
    private readonly long _totalLength;
    private double _progress = -100;

    public ProgressTracker(TextWriter logWriter, long totalLength)
    {
        _totalLength = totalLength;
        _logWriter = logWriter;
    }

    public void Report(long value)
    {
        var progress = ((double)value / _totalLength) * 100;
        if (Math.Abs(progress - _progress) > 1)
        {
            _progress = progress;
            _logWriter.WriteLine($"{Math.Round(_progress, 0)}%");
        }
    }
}
```